# Why can an API GW access a lambda that's in a private VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I'm new to AWS and struggling to understand how they've laid out their components, especially around networking & access.

In this case, I'm toying with an API GW and a "hello world" lambda. I made the lambda (no VPC) and hooked it up to an API GW, and now I have a publicly-accessible lambda. I didn't understand why the lambda was callable without being in a VPC, but I finally stumbled upon this explanation in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet

Seems weird to default open, but okay.

So, now I'm trying to close off the API via the networking-related config. So I created a VPC & private subnets (no IGW, NOT publicly accessible), and put the lambda in there. I felt confident it would no longer be accessible, 'cuz that's how VPC & networking works, yet the lambda is still publicly accessible! Why?

The API GW doesn't have access to this VPC, and in any case, this VPC doesn't have internet access. The way these components are interacting doesn't seem to make sense. What's going on here?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your desired end-goal? That is, what will you be doing with the AWS Lambda function? It might be that your use-case does not actually require an API Gateway, but we'd need to know more about how you want to use the function to make that recommendation. See also: [Creating a private API in Amazon API Gateway - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the desired end goal is an API with some form of authentication, but I haven't decided on that yet. I'm trying to get this API GW to a point that things aren't accessible, so that I can then add authentication to allow access.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein but really, the question stands alone. These networking components have specific meanings & uses. I have set them up in a way that seems to correlate with what AWS recommends yet they are behaving strangely. Why is that?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in [Creating a private API in Amazon API Gateway - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html)? It says _"To restrict access to your private API to specific VPCs and VPC endpoints, you must add aws:SourceVpc and aws:SourceVpce conditions to your API's resource policy."_

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No, thank you, I will definitely look into this. At present, I'm actually more concerned with knowing why the current setup is working when it shouldn't be. If I don't understand the fundamentals, it seems problematic to be shoveling on more details.

Comment: The API Gateway is publicly accessible. When the API Gateway receives an API call, the API Gateway _service_ (run by AWS) invokes your AWS Lambda function. This invocation is performed within the AWS infrastructure, not via the Internet or via the VPC.

Comment: Lambda functions never listen for network connections. The function isn't even instantiated until **after** a request comes in (ignoring container reuse for the moment). When a Lambda function is invoked the invocation happens via interaction with the public AWS API. After that invocation happens, AWS spins up an instance of your Lambda function, optionally connects it to your VPC if you have configured it to do so, and passes the invocation details (context and event) to the handler function.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was thinking lambdas can be **put in** a VPC. Rather, they can only be **given access to** a VPC:

> **Configuring a Lambda function to access resources in a VPC**
>
> You can configure a Lambda function to connect to private subnets in a virtual private cloud (VPC) in your AWS account.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

So all my comments about VPC logic don't apply, and that's why my lambda is publicly accessible.

Furthermore, in case this is helpful to others:

I originally had the misconception that all AWS components were basically servers, and they all needed to be put in VPCs. This pattern **does not apply** to serverless components! (including S3, lambda, dynamoDB, etc) These operate in their own area, and the point of these serverless component is to (mostly) abstract away things like networking details. Instead, they tend to control access via other methods, like IAM policies, security groups, "integrations", etc

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway allows you to create private endpoints as well as public ones. It sounds like you want a private endpoint.

Comment: You have made me realize that I've phrased the question practically, when really I'm trying to understand the theory. Updating the question...

Answer (score -2):

Check for **Internet Gateway**, **Nat gateway**. Check for the actual **VPC** the **LAMDA** is connected to, sometimes having multiple can be confusing and lastly also check the **VPC End point**